# Vue router server configuration for history mode on nginx does not work

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-routing, vue.js, vue-router

I read the following note from [vue router documentation](http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/options.html#history)

> **Note**: when using the history mode, the server needs to be properly configured so that a user directly visiting a deep link on your site
>   doesn't get a 404.

So, I try to configure my nginx like the following

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/laravel/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name working.dev;

    location /user {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php last;

    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And the following is my Vue configuration

```
var router = new VueRouter({
    hashbang: false,
    history: true,
    linkActiveClass: "active",
    root:  '/user'
});
```

But, I still got 404 when user directly visiting a deep link in my site.

**Edited**: I use Laravel routing too. The Following is my laravel routing.

```
Route::get('user', function() {
    return View::make('user.index');
});
```

Comment: so, do you fix it?

Comment: @antoniputra Yeah, with my own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just read [mattstauffer blog post](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/getting-started-using-vues-vue-router-for-single-page-apps) and finally found way to do in Laravel route. Like the following

```
Route::get('user/{vue_capture?}', function() {
    return View::make('user.index');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

It does not return 404 when user directly visiting a deep link to site.