# Removing # from url is showing me 404 after page refresh, I am using Vue Js in Laravel Application

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-router

I am developing a laravel(5.4) application  in which i am using vue js(2.0) for SPA, my problem is i want to remove #(hash) from URL.

please suggest me any solution?

This is my HTML

```
<ul class="category-list">
    <li><router-link to="/testlink.html">Tets Link</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/demotestlink.html">Demo Test LInk</router-link></li>
</ul>
```

This is my vue js code

```
export default new VueRouter({
    [
        {
            path: '/testlink.html',
            component:require('./components/demo/Testlink')
        }
    ],
    mode: 'history',
});
```

and  i have made a Testlink.vue file inside components/demo folder in Assets

Note: FYI, I am using vue.js(2.0) in Laravel(5.4) Application

Comment: Post the code from your Vuejs file(where you have written 'route' code).

Answer (score 2):

From `Vue-Router` documentation, I found this.

> The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL changes.
>
> To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which leverages the history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

I tried the above and it worked fine for me. For more information read [here](http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html)

Comment: okay, i have used the same it removed # from url, but when i reload page then it showing 404 ...

Comment: I am not sure what URL you are trying. More information would be helpful

Comment: shared some details

Comment: Got solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416359/vue-router-server-configuration-for-history-mode-on-nginx-does-not-work